# Prove of conservation of energy and momentum in linearized Einstein Field Equation

Tags: general-relativity, conservation-laws, gravitational-waves, linearized-theory

From the Linearized Einstein Field Equation, we have $\Box\bar{h}_{\mu \nu}  =-16\pi GT_{\mu \nu}$.
How can I obtain conservation of energy and momentum, $T_{\mu \nu},^{\nu}=0$, from the previous equation? Is there any extra gauge condition needed?

Comment: Yes, corrected now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need the Lorentz gauge $\partial^\mu \bar{h}_{\mu \nu}=0$ to show energy-momentum conservation. In fact, in order to derive the linearized equation of motion that you wrote, you have already used the Lorentz gauge.

Comment: Oh, so using Lorentz gauge to get linearized theory and automatically $\Box (\partial ^{\mu} \bar{h}_{\mu \nu} ) =0 \rightarrow \partial ^{\mu} T_{\mu \nu}=0$ right ?

Comment: Yes, that's right.